# Connection error with `requests` on localhost with Docker

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I'm trying to develop a client-server application but I'm running into some issues. Both my services are developed locally in a separate docker container.

The client fetches data from the api using `requests` python library. It works in production but locally, I can't use:

```py
requests.get("http://localhost:PORT/ENDPOINT")
```

It keeps giving me back:

```sh
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000): Max retries exceeded with url: /data (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f352ccd42b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

After further research, I found my answer [here](https://github.com/HTTP-APIs/hydra-python-agent/issues/104). Basically, when using Docker locally, you simply need to run:

```py
requests.get("http://host.docker.internal:PORT/ENDPOINT")
```

instead of `localhost`